# Why is Chrome rendering fallback JPEG/PNG instead of WEBP?

Tags: html, css, webp

I've been converting some images on a website I'm working on to webp to optimize page-load times and score higher on lighthouse and all of that.

I used fallbacks in my code such as below:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>WEBP image:<br> <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.webp" style="height: 80px;" /></div>

  <div>JPG image:<br> <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.sm.jpg" style="height: 80px;" /> </div>

  <div>Fallback image (JPG):<br> <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.sm.jpg" style="height: 80px;" />
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  Test image:<br>
  <picture>
    <source srcset="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.webp" type="image/webp">
    <source srcset="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.sm.jpg" type="image/jpeg">
    <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.sm.jpg">
  </picture>
</div>
```

I'm obviously testing on Chrome because I know Safari doesn't support WEBP, but it seems my chrome is always falling back on the jpeg and png files. When I inspect, I see the WEBP is in the code, and I can click it and it opens from the server so it *is* there. But Chrome isn't using it to render the page, it's immediately falling back on legacy formats.

I've been pulling my hair trying to figure out why it's not working--*maybe I used the picture tag incorrectly, etc...*--but no solution.

Finally, I linked **Modernizer** in my layout, and saw that it wasn't inserting any webp class into the html element. So I added a short script below it to see what's happening, as below:

```
<script>
    if (Modernizr.webp) {
        console.log('webp supported');
    } else {
        console.log('webp not supported');
    }
</script>
```

And the console logged the else `webp not supported`.

At this point, I'm lost. I've trying looking up online, and I see no mention of Chrome dropping WEBP support or anything. My only guess is that I'm omitting and obvious declaration or something.

Comment: In early beta versions of macOS Sierra and iOS 10, Apple added WebP support, but [it] was later removed…. WebP is unsupported in macOS and iOS Safari browser version 13 or lower. However, support is being added in Safari version 14. - Wikipedia

Comment: So it's probably an OS issue not a browser one.

Comment: According to https://caniuse.com/webp Chrome supports webp across the board, so it must be an OS problem.

Comment: @isherwood It isn't, I checked the website on chrome running on a Windows PC as well and the same issues as in the thread... :(

Comment: @Paulie_D See above comment

Comment: I've updated your post to include a functioning demo. I'm on Win10 Pro and Chrome 95. I see the WEBP image.

Comment: Interesting, I saw your update. On my macOS Chrome it's still serving on the fallback jpg. Then I checked on another Windows 10 Chrome and the same issue. Now I'm starting to think it might have something to do with the network configuring or firewall in the office... Great, thanks!